# Applescript "do shell script with administrator privileges" in Background Hangs

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, admin, osx-mavericks

On Mavericks, this works fine... [Substitute "sleep 30" with whatever long-running process you'd like.]

```
prompt% osascript -e 'do shell script "sleep 30 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"'
```

But this doesn't actually fork into the background; it waits the full 30 seconds:

```
prompt% osascript -e 'do shell script "sleep 30 >/dev/null 2>&1 &" with administrator privileges'
```

It worked okay prior to Mavericks...  Does anybody know how to make "do shell script" return right away, without waiting for its descendant processes to finish?

PS – I've even tried things like:

```
prompt% cat /tmp/sleep.sh
#!/bin/sh

(sleep 30 >/dev/null 2>&1 &)

prompt% osascript -e 'do shell script "sh /tmp/sleep.sh" with administrator privileges'
```

i.e., create a shell script that completely disowns the sleep process...  No dice.  I also thought that maybe using setpgrp() to change the process group to something else (via a Perl wrapper) might help...  Nada.  :-(

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
do shell script "sleep 30 &>/dev/null &"
```

Comment: that fixed it for me on El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug on Mavericks, apparently introduced in 10.9.2. (I didn't see it in 10.9.1; I have a couple of apps that depend heavily on this functionality.) Please file a Radar/bug with Apple to ensure that they fix it.